# Node.js and MySQL backend app is not getting containerized with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I am facing a problem while containerizing my node.js + mysql backend app using docker. The node app and mysql database works perfectly in my local system but while containerizing it the connection between node and mysql container is not being set up and mysql doesn't gets connected to nodeapp.

**Folder Structure:**
[folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjEf0.png)

**database.js file**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();
// Create a MySQL connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.MYSQLDB_HOST,
user: process.env.MYSQLDB_USER,
password: process.env.MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD,
port: process.env.NODE_LOCAL_PORT,
database: process.env.MYSQLDB_DATABASE
});

connection.connect((err) =\> {
if (err) {
console.error('Error connecting to MySQL: ' + err.stack);
return;
}
console.log('Connected to MySQL as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

module.exports = connection;
```

**docker-compose.yml file :**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql_container
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./dbinit/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
      - $HOME/database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    networks:
      - internalnet

  nodeapp:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nodeapp_container
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    image: nodeapp_backend
    ports:
      - $NODE_LOCAL_PORT:$NODE_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysqldb
      - DB_USER=$MYSQLDB_USER
      - DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - DB_NAME=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
      - DB_PORT=$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    networks:
      - internalnet

networks:
  internalnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM node:alpine3.11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

**.env file:**

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=hiru
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=assignments_db
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3306
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306
NODE_LOCAL_PORT=3000
NODE_DOCKER_PORT=3000
MYSQLDB_HOST=mysqldb
```

**app.js file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const authenticationRoutes = require('./src/routes/authentication');
const assignmentsRoutes = require('./src/routes/assignments');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/auth', authenticationRoutes);
app.use('/assignments', assignmentsRoutes);


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to the Assignments API");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**here is what i get when i run the `docker-compose up` command:**
[Log of containers after running the compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4wR.png)

Comment: Add ```env_file: .env``` in mysql service also else add Hard coded values for ```$MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT```

Comment: it is not working even using hardcoded values like 3306:3306

Comment: @Hiren Timbadiya Welcome to SO..! if the below answer resolves your issue please don't forget to mark it as accepted and update the status.

Answer (score 1):

The information you set in JS (`database.js` file) for db connection is wrong: you must rely on compose environment variable set for `nodeapp`:

From

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.MYSQLDB_HOST,
user: process.env.MYSQLDB_USER,
password: process.env.MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD,
port: process.env.NODE_LOCAL_PORT,
database: process.env.MYSQLDB_DATABASE
});
```

To

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
user: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
port: process.env.DB_PORT,
database: process.env.DB_NAME
});
```

Comment: I think this answer is right, but can you [edit] it to point out which specific port reference is wrong and what should be changed?

Comment: sorry I was using mobile phone, I fix that

Comment: It is not working even if i change env file like you just suggested

Comment: Did you first verify mysql is up and running via docker logs and mysql client ?